# Enumerating AD Security Group memberships for a User in ASP.Net 5/core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

So I see lots of information on how to do this under older ASP.Net versions, but I cannot find any information regarding how to get a list/enumeration of a User's security group memberships under ASP.Net 5/core (as an aside - which one is the official name now?).

I would even appreciate any information on how to just check for membership of a single AD group - I've tried both `User.IsInRole(@"mySGDomain\mySGName)`, which always returns false, as well as the Authorize annotation: `[Authorize(Roles = @"mySGDomain\mySGName")]`, which also fails. I've also gone in debug mode to try and inspect the list of Claims that I can see under the `User.Identities` enumeration, and none of them look like anything related to AD group memberships.

Am I missing anything obvious here? Is there any documentation on how to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsInRole is broken in Rc1 but will be fixed in Rc2. Unfortunately the directory services pieces have not made it into core nor will they be there by RTM (no I don't have a date!)

If all you need is IsInRole rc2 is your answer. You could test the nightly builds to make sure.